# How to output sound on Freebox Server/Player?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, banshee

The french internet provider Free is providing AirPlay support for its two boxes (http://www.free.fr/adsl/freebox-revolution.html) the player and the server. By AirPlay I mean here, a way to output sound on either the server or the player from a computer using the local network.

The big picture of it works is not very clear to me, but it seems the protocol stack implemented on the boxes is the Apple Protocol (are there deals between the 2 companies, or is this protocol open, I don't know ?)

Anyway, using Itunes either on Mac or on Windows one can easily output the music being played on the Server or on the player by just choosing where to output the sound from a menu entry. It just work.

From Ubuntu software repositories, I installed `pulseaudio-module-raop` and I am now able to see my Player and my Server in the output list of the sound menu. Nevertheless, any of these two entry is working, no sound is outputed and my banshee starts to play song very very quickly. After digging into this problem if my understanding is correct, it seems that the protocol version implemented by the Free boxes is a newer one that is not supported by pulsaudio. I tried the following pulseaudio patch without success:

http://hfujita.github.io/pulseaudio-raop2/

So my question is, does someone succeded into outputing sound from Ubuntu to a free equipement using AirPlay ? If yes, of course I am intersted in knowing how ?

Update: a screenshot of the output tab of the sound configuration panel showing that my two Free devices are discovered. Selecting any one of this output doesn't work and in Banshee for example when these outputs are selected music is played 5 time faster than normal time.

[image]

Comment: Your problem is about pulseaudio ??

Comment: @KasiyA the link I provided to pulseaudio-raop2 contains a full git fork of the pulseaudio code I think with an additional plugin. I think my problem is somewhere related to pulse audio because it's the default sound-server for ubuntu and I think the problem is in the pulseaudio-module-raop.

Comment: PulseAudio is working fine ! I can output sound on my integrated speakers (I have a dell laptop). The problem is with the pulseaudio-module-raop able to detect my AirPlay devices but not to output sound other there. It seems normal because the protocol supported by my devices is not the one supported by this module. That's why I reached the pulseaudio-raop2 project, but was not able to have it working

Comment: See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1220232#p1220232

Comment: Thanks for the link. It confirm what I read elsewhere: the module raop from pulseaudio doesn't support the devices I have. They also link to the pulseaudio-raop2 project, but unfortunately I was not able to properly use it and asked a question here: https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2/issues/10 I'll give a try to RAOP play. Are you able to stream sound on AirPlay devices from Ubuntu yourself ?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-raop` if not fixed 
take a Screenshot from `Output` tab in your sound setting Please and post it on your question.

Comment: I already have the pulseaudio-module-raop as I said previously. i updated the question with the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The Freebox probably makes use of Shairport/Airport Express 2nd gen. These only use UDP while Pulseaudio-raop is only capable of using TCP. It is a known bug and already existing for several years :(
Please subscribe to the bug at launchpad to generate as much exposure as possible to get it fixed soon :D
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/951120

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the link. yes I read somewhere that the Freebox uses Shairport/Airport Express 2nd gen based on UDP. Ijust subscribed to the bug also hopping it will be fixed soon.

Comment: This Q/A might be useful: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/12595 - it uses this raop2 pulseaudio module: http://hfujita.github.io/pulseaudio-raop2/